# I'm trying to split lines without using split

Tags: python, variable-assignment

"""
this produces what i need it to, but i need to do the same thing without using split. Our professor has only taught us how to use split and strip but he wants us to not use split 
"""

```
def main ():
    textFileName= input('file name')
    countWords(textFileName )

def countWords(textFileName ):
        file=open(textFileName)
        count=[]
        for line in open (textFileName):

              count.extend(line.split())

        print(count)
        print(len(count))

main()
```

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47627/is-this-a-good-implementation-of-the-split-function for the different ways to implement `split` :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall` function.

```
count.extend(re.findall(r'\S+', line))
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "foo bar buzz"
>>> s.split()
['foo', 'bar', 'buzz']
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', s)
['foo', 'bar', 'buzz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for that purpose. If your professor has a background in functional languages, he will surely appreciate:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> line = "abc def    ghi"

>>> ["".join(token) 
     for space, token in itertools.groupby(line, key=lambda c: c.isspace())
     if not space]
#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#    keep only non                                   group together
#    space sequences                                 consecutive chars
#    in the result                                   based on the result
#                                                    of `isspace`

['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom split method:

```
class Str(str):
    def split(self, sep=None, maxsplit=-1):
        if sep is not None and len(sep) != 1:
            return NotImplemented  # Can't figure out how to do seps longer than 1...
        whole = []
        curr = []
        for i in self:
            if i not in (sep or "\n \t"):
                curr.append(i)
            elif curr != []:
                whole.append("".join(curr))
                curr = []
        whole.append("".join(curr))
        if sep is None:
            whole = [i for i in whole if i != ""]
        if maxsplit > -1:
            whole[maxsplit:] = ["".join(whole[maxsplit])]
        return whole
```

Then use it like:

```
my_str = Str("Hello, How are you, List Item here, Index blah, Gonna split")
print(my_str.split())
# Output:
['Hello,', 'How', 'are', 'you,', 'List', 'Item', 'here,', 'Index', 'blah,', 'Gonna', 'split']
```

You can make that a function if not a class:

```
def split(str_to_split, sep=None, max_split=-1):
    if sep is not None and len(sep) != 1:
        return NotImplemented
    whole = []
    curr = []
    for i in str_to_split:
        if i not in (sep or "\n \t"):
            curr.append(i)
        elif curr != []:
            whole.append("".join(curr))
            curr = []
    whole.append("".join(curr))
    if sep is None:
        whole = [i for i in whole if i != ""]
    if maxsplit > -1:
        whole[maxsplit:] = ["".join(whole[maxsplit])]
    return whole
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning to use regular expressions is going to be very, very, very useful, so definitely try and understand Avinash's example.  And itertools is a very powerful library.

One other possibility is `"".partition()`

```
s = "foo bar fizz buzz"
l = []

while True:
    res = s.partition(' ')
    l.append(res[0])
    if not res[2]:
        break
    s = res[2]

for w in l:
    print w
```

This can be extended to do more than one line.